# How to set a custom view in actionbar in android?

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I want to use a custom font in actionbar app title but Every time I am getting the same error (nullpointer exception) and my app says me that "`Unfortunately **** has stopped` ". I have searched a lot and tried to use them. But nothings working. The same error keeps happening.  I have created a simple layout with a TextView and trying to insert it in the actionbar by this line

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```

Whatever I do, the `setCustomView` sends me the nullpointer error. I am thinking that if I can set the layout in actionbar it will be easy to change the TextView font. Here is my full code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

    }
}
```

and the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/App_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Prime" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tushar.primeplay2/com.example.tushar.primeplay2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.tushar.primeplay2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using android studio.

Comment: Are you using support library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

If you are using support library

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

otherwise

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

and then

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Your `onCreate` should look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // As you said you are using support library
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    actionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);

}
}
```

Remember to import

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

rather than

```
import android.app.ActionBar
```

Comment: I am using support library.

Comment: Ok, then try what I have mentioned in my answer. Remember to import support library classes not normal one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The error has gone. But the app title has not changed. In custom_actionbar layout the TextView's text is "Prime". This should show "Prime". Its pulling the data from app_name variable which is defined in strings.xml

Comment: Please post a new question for that. That is unrelated to this one.

Comment: Also please accept this as answer if it helped you.

Comment: sure. I am just figuring out the problem. I just totally changed the custom_actionbar. I made it yellow. But the actionbar is black with with a white text. I think its not loading the layout, right?

Comment: use this line actionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); before setting the view. See my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 mSupportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 mSupportActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
 mSupportActionBar.setCustomView (R.layout.action_bar_lt);
```