# top navigation bar with button and title

Tags: android

I am making a `android` version app based on the `iOS` one, however, I am in trouble of making the top navigation bar. I actually want to create an action bar that is similar to the `iOS` interface, however, I cannot add `close button`, `go back button`, and `next button`.

Firstly, if it is home activity, the top navigation bar will contain a centered title and a `close button`, which is used to close the current activity. Like below:

[image]

Then, if the user has got a correct answer (or under some conditions), then `next button` will show up, if not, it won't show up.

[image]
[image]

Just like the above pictures, in picture 1, user can go back to Q1, as Q1 is already correct. Also, Q2 is also correct, as it can go to Q3. Then, in picture 2, Q3 is not answered yet, it cannot go to Q4, but it is allowed to go to Q2. And if it goes to Q2, the same interface of picture 1 will be shown (still contains the next, and back button.

I am now have an action bar, but cannot do anything but only with a title.

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Problems"
  android:configChanges=
     "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|
      screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
  android:theme="@style/AccountSetting"
  android:label="Problems" />
```

toolbarlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/chtl_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chtl_useIMG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nilu" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nilu" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nilu" />


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

abs_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/app_name"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:id="@+id/mytext"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
public class Problems extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.chtl_toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="AccountSetting" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this use custom `Toolbar` like this

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/chtl_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chtl_useIMG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilu" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilu" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilu" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

than set this toolbar as your action bar in your `onCreate()` method of activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ar_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

add this theme

```
<style name="AccountSetting" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>


</style>
```

**EDIT** you activity problem layout add this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbarlayout"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/app_name"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:id="@+id/mytext"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**you activity code**

```
public class Problems extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
     LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);   
     getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: @androidnewbie can u explain more

Comment: Just append the `Toolbar` into my `.xml` file, or create a new one?

Comment: @androidnewbie create a new  toolbar

Comment: i am new to android, can tell how to create it pls?

Comment: create a new layout my frined and add this toolbar in it

Comment: error at setSupportActionBar(toolbar); java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @androidnewbie you need to use no action bar theme in this activity

Comment: @androidnewbie remove that line

Comment: i added this android:theme="@style/AccountSetting" in manifest

Comment: Since the id is @+id/chtl_toolbar in your toolbar.xml, so i do this Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.chtl_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: can include the toolbarlayout in other way pls, as i am using webview to be the content

Comment: try this **`LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);`**

Comment: like this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670715/7666442 @androidnewbie

Comment: I give up on that and gonna change approach, but thanks a lot.